# Find $\sum_{i=1}^3 \frac {P(x_{1})-x_{1}^{3}}{P'(x_{1})}$ for $P(x)=x^{3}-x^{2}-x+a$, $a \in R $

Tags: calculus, algebra-precalculus, derivatives, polynomials

$$ P(x)=x^{3}-x^{2}-x+a, a \in R $$
If$$ \ x_{1} \neq x_{2} \neq x_{3}$$ then:
$$ {P(x_{1})-x_{1}^{3}\over P'(x_{1})}+{P(x_{2})-x_{2}^{3}\over P'(x_{2})}+{P(x_{3})-x_{3}^{3}\over P'(x_{3})} =?$$
I used that $x_{1}$,$ x_{2}$,$x_{3}$ is roots for the P, hence $$P(x_{1})=0, P(x_{2})=0,P(x_{3})=0$$
$$ P'(x)=(x-x_{2})(x-x_{3})+(x-x_{1})(x-x_{3})+(x-x_{1})(x-x_{2})$$
From this I don't know what to do. Even if i get common denominator for this fractions, I don't get anywhere. Some help please. Thank you.

Comment: Is it given that $x_1,x_2,x_3$ are the roots of $P$? Although it wouldn't make much sense in the context of the expression.

Comment: Yes it is, it says these are roots of P and are different.

Comment: Then what's the point of having $P(x_i)$ in the epxression? Because it will be $0$ anyways.

Comment: Perhaps a suggestion for the method?

Comment: Using the factor theorem you have $P(x)=k(x-x_1)(x-x_2)(x-x_3)$ and you know $k=1$. This might help

Comment: I used that up if you look closley.

Comment: I see - didn't see that's how you got $P'$

Answer (score 3):

Let $F(x)=\frac{P(x)-x^3}{P(x)}$. Then, (as the degree of $P(x)-x^3$ is $<$ the degree of $P(x)$, and the $x_k$ distincts), we can expand $F$ in simple fractions as
 $$F(x)=\sum_{k=1}^3\frac{P(x_k)-x_k^3}{P^{\prime}(x_k)(x-x_k)}$$

Now multiply by $x$, and let $x\to \infty$, we get 
 $$-1=\sum_{k=1}^3\frac{P(x_k)-x_k^3}{P^{\prime}(x_k)}$$